# Autocomplete with Webservice fails ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, autocomplete

I'm trying to use a web service for an auto complete text box that reads from the database.  When I try to compile I get the error

`HttpExceptionUnhandled`
Markup and JS with indication of where the exception occurs

```
   <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"
                type="text/javascript"></script>
            <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"
                rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
                        source: function (request, response) {
                            $.ajax({
 error on this line             url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Service.asmx/GetDrugs") %>',
                                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                success: function (data) {
                                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                        return {
                                            label: item.split('-')[0],
                                            val: item.split('-')[1]
                                        }
                                    }))
                                },
                                error: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                },
                                failure: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        select: function (e, i) {
                            $("#txtHidden").val(i.item.val);
                        },
                        minLength: 1
                    });

                }); 
            </script>


            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="txtHidden" runat="server" />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="Submit" />
            </form>

    </asp:Content>
```

When I try to run the web service in a browser I can see the list of methods available and click on `GetDrugs` and it takes me to a screen where I can enter text, and it also fails.  When it fails I get the following text in my browser

error that happens when I try to invoke the web service.  This is after reforming the SQL and adding a ToString() to the reader in the while loop.

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at System.String.Format(String format, Object arg0)
   at Service.GetDrugs(String prefix) in c:\Users\dtceci2\Desktop\WebSite2\App_Code\Service.cs:line 45
```

The connection string is fine and SQL Server is running on my local machine.  Here is the code for the web service

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Service_CS
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://localhost/~Service.asmx")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Service()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string[] GetDrugs(string prefix)
    {
        List<string> drugs= new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select distinct drug_name from rx where drug_name like @SearchText" + "'%'";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        drugs.Add(string.Format("{0}}", rdr["drug_name"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return drugs.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

The code behind for my page with the markup is simply

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string drugName = Request.Form[txtSearch.Text];

    }
}
```

Any clues on what I'm messing up?

Comment: ur `WebMethod` is `GetCustomers`....where is `GetDrugs`??

Comment: I would suggest opening up `Fiddler` and checking the data you are sending to the web service.  It could be malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plus sign is missing in the query. It should be:

```
"select distinct drug_name from rx where drug_name like @SearchText + '%'";
```

The SQL that's currently getting sent to SQL Server is:

```
 select distinct drug_name from rx where drug_name like @SearchText'%'
```

which is of course no good.

Comment: now that part of the problem, now there's a format exception.  thanks, though :)

Comment: The FormatException is due to your extra `}` in your string, where you have `string.Format("{0}}"`

Comment: ugh, I'm a noob and have been slogging through this for a while now.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Append the '%' to the incoming variable before using it in the parameter so you don't have to be concerned about concatenation in the SQL SELECT.

```
prefix += "%";
```

Fixed GetCustomers() function:

```
   public string[] GetCustomers(string prefix)
    {
        prefix += "%";
        List<string> customers = new List<string>();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                    .ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select distinct drug_name from rx where drug_name like @SearchText";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", prefix);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        customers.Add(rdr["drug_name"].toString());
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            return customers.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the addition of adding the wild cad to the `prefix` variable, but this is still giving me the error `System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.` even if I make rdr["drug_name"].ToString()

Comment: If you are creating a `List` of strings, you shouldn't need the `string.format`. try `customers.Add(rdr["drug_name"].toString());` I updated the code in my answer.